# Javascript: how to get line/col caret position in textarea?

Tags: javascript, textarea, caret

I can not find the solution. I've tried to assume that count of  \n symbols is the same with lines count, but sometimes this method works incorrectly (e.g. after paste text from clipboard)
i've tried different jQuery plugins, but still unsuccessfully.
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The descision is not so simple and requieres large amount of javascript code. So, finally i've used CodeMirror Project by Marijn Haverbeke  (https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror)

Comment: Isn't that amazing that there isn't trivial API for this in browsers? WTF?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do this:

Take the text content only up to `selectionStart` then make it an array by splitting at `eol`

```
p = $('#Form_config').val().substr(0, $('#Form_config')[0].selectionStart).split("\n");

// line is the number of lines
line = p.length;

// col is the length of the last line
col = p[p.length-1].length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
var pos = getCaretPos(document.formName.textareaName);

function getCaretPos(obj)
{
  obj.focus();

  if(obj.selectionStart) return obj.selectionStart;//Gecko
  else if (document.selection)//IE
  {
    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
    var clone = sel.duplicate();
    sel.collapse(true);
    clone.moveToElementText(obj);
    clone.setEndPoint('EndToEnd', sel);
    return clone.text.length;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: and how can it help to determine at which line and column the caret is?