# HTML Textarea: is it possible to change cursor position?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to change cursor position in textarea element using Javascript code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140637/javascript-how-to-get-line-col-caret-position-in-textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES

```
function SetCursorPosition(pos)
{
    // HERE txt is the text field name
    var obj=document.getElementById('<%= txt.ClientID %><%= txt.ClientID %>');

    //FOR IE
    if(obj.setSelectionRange)
    {
        obj.focus();
        obj.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);
    }

    // For Firefox
    else if (obj.createTextRange)
    {
        var range = obj.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', pos);
        range.moveStart('character', pos);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

FROM :: http://shawpnendu.blogspot.com/2009/03/javascript-how-to-setget-cursor.html

Answer (score 1):

This post may help you [Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea)

Comment: And this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286595/update-textarea-value-but-keep-cursor-position